# Django + Javascript - How can we verify that the Django value is not null for execute Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

With Django ORM and Javascript:

How can we verify that the var1 value is not null?

```
{% for station in stations0 %}
var var1 = {{station.punto_comunicacion.latitud}};
if (var1 != None) {
    latlngs.push(new L.LatLng({{ station.latitud }},{{ station.longitud }}));
    latlngs.push(new L.LatLng({{ station.punto_comunicacion.latitud}},{{ station.punto_comunicacion.longitud}}));
}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if (var1) { .. }` is sufficient: *assuming* that the text of {{station.punto_comunicacion.latitud}} is valid JavaScript. I suspect it is not and the issue is there is 'None' "all over" in the resulting JS, making for multiple syntax errors. (Include the _actual_ HTML snippet in such questions.)

Comment: A cleaner approach would be to use JSON to transfer the entire object into JS, then work on that. See https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/02/18/safely-including-data-for-javascript-in-a-django-template/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this **station.punto_comunicacion.latitud** was giving None, then your javascript will become like this

```
var var1 = None;
```

In this case, the js will be looking for a variable **None** as **None**'s equivalent in js is **null**.

You can use the django template filter 'default_if_none' instead. In your case it would be

```
var var1 = {{station.punto_comunicacion.latitud|default_if_none:"null"}};
```

Which will make your js

```
var var1 = null;
```

And you can check the if condition the usual way

```
if(var1){
  ...
}
```

Reference: [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none)